# Obtain height and width of a container, have SVG resize to fit on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, responsive-design

Basically, the goal here is to get the SVG, which is located within an `<object>` to resize if the `<object>`'s parent wrapper height is less than the SVG. What happens now is the SVG overflows... However, the SVG is responsive when resizing the width.

Here's *part* of my jquery, the relative part.

```
var a = document.getElementById("theSVG");

    a.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var SVGfit = function() {
            var containerWidth;
            var containerHeight;

            if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
                containerWidth = $("#wrapper").width;
                containerHeight = $("#wrapper").height; //get the SVG wrapper container size
            }
            var svgTag = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
            var svgBox = svgTag.viewBox.baseVal;

            svgBox.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 "+ containerWidth+ " "+containerHeight);
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize",SVGfit,false);
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="svg">
            <object data="MonroeJeff.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="theSVG"></object>
    </section> <!--close svg-->
</div><!--close wrapper-->
```

a link to the site I'm working on:
http://zadias.me/SVG/Monroe%20Jefferson/MonroeJeff.html

notice how if you resize your window in terms of height, the SVG overflows, but the wrapper border does adapt.

The goal: resize based on height of parent.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It's funny, I was trying for the reverse, to have the <object> enclosing an SVG resize itself to fit the dimensions of the SVG (particularly when the enclosed SVG resizes.  Firefox works, IE11 doesn't or is very iffy, anyways.  I'll keep watching for answers.